# Some of my HTML classes don't apply CSS code in PHP file

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know where is the problem in my code, some of html `class` can't apply the css code like the first class `class="foot"`, here are my files

```css
* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.foot {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  bottom: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.h2Foot {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-family: "Audiowild";
}

.ulContact {
  list-style: none;
}

.afoot {
  color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.afoot:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(43, 188, 255);
}

.pfoot {
  color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.hrfoot {
  border: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168);
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.lbllogofoot {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Audiowild";
}

.pCopyrightFoot {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Audiowwild";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/footer.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- bootstrap 4 css CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- font-awesome CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- font family -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide">
</head>

<body>
  <footer class="foot">
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="mt-4 mb-2 text-center">
          <h2 class="h2Foot">Social media</h2>
          <ul class="ulContact mt-2">
            <li class="d-inline-block p-1">
              <a href="#" target="_blank" class="afoot"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="d-inline-block p-1">
              <a href="#" target="_blank" class="afoot"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="d-inline-block p-1">
              <a href="#" class="afoot" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="d-inline-block p-1">
              <a href="#" class="afoot" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="mt-4 mb-2 text-center">
          <h2 class="h2Foot">Shipping to</h2>
          <p class="pfoot">Shippinh to all United Nations Member States</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="mt-4 mb-2 text-center">
          <h2 class="h2Foot">Our products</h2>
          <p class="pfoot">High quality & Low price + Guarantee for 3 months</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="mt-4 mb-2 text-center">
          <h2 class="h2Foot">Paymen methods</h2>
          <ul class="ulContact mt-2">
            <li class="d-inline-block p-1">
              <a href="#" target="_blank" class="afoot"><i class="fab fa-cc-visa"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="d-inline-block p-1">
              <a href="#" target="_blank" class="afoot"><i class="fab fa-cc-mastercard"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="d-inline-block p-1">
              <a href="#" class="afoot" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-paypal"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hrfoot">
    <div class="row mt-2 mb-4">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-4">
        <img src="../pics/demologo.png" alt="demologo" width="70px" height="60px"><label class="lbllogofoot">Logo</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12 mt-4">
        <p class="pCopyrightFoot pt-3">© 2020 Copyright: <strong>ozaoujal07@gmail.com</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- font-awesome js CDN -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap 4 js CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

here is the output:

[image]

here is the DevTools:
I see the class in the element and I can't see it on a styles

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95dLP.png)

Comment: When you click on an element in DevTools, the Style sidebar will show how all the styles are applied to it. You should be able to see why you're not getting the styles you expect.

Comment: Sometimes Bootstrap-4 CSS takes precedence.

Comment: Could you be specific about what's wrong with the output?

Comment: Thanks sir, but here is the problem, I can't see the class foot in the styles of DevTools, while I can see it on elements,  does it mean css didn't applied this class!?

Comment: You should always see the class in the sidebar, even if the styles are overridden (it will strike them out). Are you sure you see `class="foot"` in the elements?

Comment: the footer have a class called `<footer class="foot">` this class in a css: `.foot {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  bottom: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}` this css code didn't applied

Comment: That makes no sense. If it really has the class in the Elements panel, you should see it in the Styles sidebar.\

Comment: okay, I'll take screenshot to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's work correctly, Did you try clear cache with CTRL + F5?
[image]